# Is Malaweg/Malaueg a language or a dialect?

Tags: austronesian

I'm so confused, i got into [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org), and searched up 'Philippine Languages', until i came across the [Northern Luzon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_Luzon_languages) Languages, and within the family i found the [Cagayan Valley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cagayan_Valley_languages) languages, I found the [Malaweg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malaweg_language) language, i red the first line of text and it said this:

> Malaweg (Malaueg) is spoken by the Malaweg people in the northern part of the Philippines. As per Ethnologue, it is a dialect of the Itawis language.

I looked at the family tree and saw this:

> Austronesian >
> Malayo-Polynesian >
> Philippine >
> Northern Luzon >
> Cagayan Valley >
> Itawis >
> Malaweg

I quickly realized it's inside the [Itawis Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itawis_language), making it a dialect, However, i still can't figure out if it's a dialect or a language, because as the line says

> As per Ethnologue, it is a dialect of the Itawis Language

I do not know what to trust, Ethnologue or Wikipedia

Comment: There is no clear definition of what a dialect or a language is, so the answer is _yes_, it is indeed a language or a dialect.

Comment: as the famous saying goes, "a shprakh iz a dyalekt mit an armey un flot" (the quote is in Yiddish, but I suspect the gist is understandable in English, and the translation is well known)

Comment: When even the Ethnologue (they are notorious splitters) calls it a dialect, it is one.

Comment: @Tristan i can't understand. can you translate it for me?

Comment: "a language is a dialect with an army and a navy", although the word "flot" is cognate with English "fleet", "navy" is the usual translationhere

Answer (score 0):

According to the most reliable listing, Glottolog, Malaweg is a separate language.  https://glottolog.org/resource/languoid/id/mala1534

Comment: What makes Glottolog “the most reliable listing”, in particular, more reliable than Ethnologue (or even Wikipedia)?